# PHP Creating new variable for each time a link in an iframe changes

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a basic html form page where a user enters a word and it submits to a php page with an iframe in it and it searches the term in wikipedia see below:

```
<?php

$userEntered = $_POST["userEntered"];

echo
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="EN">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Full Page IFrame</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {overflow: auto;}
html, body, div, iframe {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; border: none;}
iframe {display: block; width: 100%; border: none; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="tree" name="tree" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' . $userEntered . '" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

I want to know how to create a new variable each time a user clicks on a link on the wikipedia page.

It seems that the $userEntered variable stays the same even if you navigate to a new wikipeia page in the iframe.

Comment: put a text field in form then submit it and set target= iframe

Comment: iframe contents are totally independent webpages. links clicked in there cannot affect the containing page. not unless they've got a `target="_top"` or some JS code to break out of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

this is working as you wanted (tested code)

```
<?php
$userEntered = !empty($_POST["userEntered"])?$_POST["userEntered"]:'test';

echo
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="EN">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Full Page IFrame</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {overflow: auto;}
html, body, div, iframe {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; border: none;}
iframe {display: block; width: 100%; border: none; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" >
<input type="text" name="userEntered">
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
<iframe id="tree" name="tree" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' . $userEntered . '" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto"></iframe>

</body>
</html>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (unless you have control of the wikipedia domain).

You can't retrieve the URL of an iframe, and that's a good thing. If it was possible anyone could set up an webpage and retrieve sensitive information form the URL.

It's the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Also, PHP is a server-side language, it just generates the page and passes it along, what happens after that is not something PHP cares about. Use javascript to detect changes in a page.

**Edit: Solution for situations where same-origin is not a problem**

To pass the URL of an iframe to PHP when changed you would have to fetch and send the URL using javascript.

Simple example using jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#tree').load(function() {
        var frameUrl = $('#tree').contents().get(0).location.href;
        $.post("backend.php", {url: frameUrl});
    });
});
```

```php
<?php

// Make sure it exists and filter it if necessary.
$url = $_POST['url'];
```